# How to add a class implementing an interface to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, polymorphism

To go around having to implement ALL the methods in an interface, I created an abstract class that implements an interface, then have other classes extend the abstract class and override only the needed methods.

**I am building an API /  Framework for my app.**

I would like to add classes that are instances of an interface **`IMyInterface`** to an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Class<IMyInterface>> classes = new ArrayList<>();  
classes.add(MyClass.class);
```

Here is **MyClass**

```
class MyClass extends AbstractIMyInterface {}
```

Here is **AbstractIMyInterface**

```
class AbstractIMyInterface implements IMyInterface {}
```

So far this seems impossible. My approach above won't work:

> `add (java.lang.Class<com.app.IMyInterface>)
>
>   in ArrayList cannot be applied to
>
>   (java.lang.Class<com.myapp.plugin.plugin_a.MyClass>)`

How can I make this work, ie: Add a class extending another class to an **`ArrayList`**

Comment: Looks like you trying to add the object of a class which is not the object of `IMyInterface`

Comment: Thank you for the response. What is the right way to do it @Prashant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use wildcard `? extends IMyInterface`.

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
```

In `ArrayList<Class<IMyInterface>> classes` , you can only add `Class<IMyInterface>`.

Comment: I just accepted your answer @ramanlfc. I am, however, struggling to iterate through `ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>> classes = new ArrayList<>();`. I posted a follow up question, [How to interate a ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069784/how-to-interate-a-arraylistclass-extends-imyinterface), if you could help. Thank you for the help so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?` for that.

```
List<Class <? extends IMyInterface>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to add this way, hope this is helpful

```
 public class MyClass extends AbstractIMyInterface {
    @Override
    public void onEating() {
        //from interface
    }

    @Override
    void onRunning() {
        //from abstract
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<IMyInterface> iMyInterfaces = new ArrayList<>();
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        iMyInterfaces.add(myClass);

    }
}
```