# How to interate a ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>>

Tags: java, arraylist, interface, iteration

I have an `ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>> classes = new ArrayList<>();`. When I try to iterate it, I get:

```
Incopatible types:  
Required: java.lang.Class <? extends IMyInterface>  
Found: IMyInterface
```

**My iteration**

```
for (IMyInterface iMyInterface : IMyInterface.getMyPluggables()) {}
```

**Red code warning highlight (Android Studio)**

```
Error:(35, 90) error: incompatible types: Class<? extends IMyInterface> cannot be converted to IMyInterface
```

I would like to

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>> classes = new ArrayList<>();

for (Class<? extends IMyInterface> myClass : classes) {
    if (myClass instanceof IMyInterface) {
        View revPluggableViewLL = myClass.getMyInterfaceMethod();
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Class<capture<? extends com.myapp.IMyInterface>>' to 'com.myapp.IMyInterface'
```

How can I go about iterating through it?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You try to iterate a `ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>>` not a `ArrayList<IMyInterface>`. And by the way, this is not what you want... `Class` is an instance representing the type, not an instance of that type itself. So `instanceof IMyInterface` will never be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to iterate on instances of `IMyInterface` as you want to invoke a specific method of `IMyInterface` :

```
    View revPluggableViewLL = myClass.getMyInterfaceMethod();
```

The problem is that you declared a `List` of `Class` instances :

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
```

It doesn't contain any instance of  `IMyInterface` but only `Class` instances.

To achieve your need, declare a list of `IMyInterface` :

```
List<IMyInterface> instances = new ArrayList<>();
```

And use it in this way :

```
for (IMyInterface myInterface : instances ) {
   View revPluggableViewLL = myInterface.getMyInterfaceMethod();   
}
```

Note that this check is not required :

```
if (myClass instanceof IMyInterface) {
    View revPluggableViewLL = myClass.getMyInterfaceMethod();
}
```

You manipulate a `List` of `IMyInterface`, so elements of the `List` are necessarily instances of `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Thanks for the responce @davidxxx. With that, I won't be able to add instances of `IMyInterface` to `List<IMyInterface> instances = new ArrayList<>();`. I need `ArrayList<Class<? extends IMyInterface>> instances = new ArrayList<>();` so that I can do `instances.add(AClassOfIMyInterface.class);`. Would you have any suggestions that would fix it? Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. Why do you think that you need to `Class`es in your List ? `Class`es represent class structure/definition and not instances of `IMyInterface`.

Comment: This is a follow up to a question I had asked earlier, [How to add a class implementing an interface to an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067888/how-to-add-a-class-implementing-an-interface-to-an-arraylist), in which I accepted the [Ramanlfc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47068064/3663765).

Comment: I read it. The problem is that your initial guesswork was wrong. You said in this question : "I would like to add classes that are instances of an interface IMyInterface to an ArrayList:" but technically this is not correct. Your classes are not instances of  `IMyInterface` at all.  You didn't need to have a `List` of `Class`. What you want is a `List` of `IMyInterface` to manipulate instances of `IMyInterface`. `List` of `Class` is a very specific  requirement that generally relies on reflection. You don't mention it and don't seem to need it either. Forget that for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

`myClass` is an instance of `Class`, which doesn't implement `IMyInterface` (even if it's `Class<IMyInterface>`). Therefore you can never execute `getMyInterfaceMethod()` on `myClass`.